# Custom Post Type Get Url Loop ShortCode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, shortcode

I have a PHP script here I can't seem to wrap my head around, im basically trying to create a shortcode that displays the next custom post type url, then when the current post is also the last post, it loops back pulling the url to the first post.
everything works except for when you are on the final post, the shortcode displays the ID of the current post (final post) instead of the url of the first post, I am assuming it has something to do with " 'fields'  => 'ids' " but i have no idea as I don't write php:

```
function next_post_url() {
$next_post = get_next_post();
if(!$next_post){
    $args = array(
      'numberposts' => 1,
      'post_type'   => 'portfolio',
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      'fields'  => 'ids'
    );
    $first_post = get_posts( $args );
    $next_post_url = $first_post[0];
}
else{
    $next_post_url = get_next_post()->post_title;
}
return get_permalink($next_post->ID);}add_shortcode( 'next_post_url', 'next_post_url' );
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code for the get_posts() and get_next_post() functions?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go please modify your php code as shown below.

```
function next_post_url() {
   $next_post = get_next_post();
   if (!$next_post) {
     $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'fields' => 'ids'
     );
     $first_post = get_posts($args);
     $post = $first_post[0];
   } else {
     $post = $next_post;
   }
   return get_permalink($post);
}
add_shortcode('next_post_url', 'next_post_url');
```